# How to send multiple parameter from android to wcf server using ksoap2

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2

I am making a application using wcf web service.

I want to send multiple parameter but only thing I know is like this

```
request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtData.getText().toString());
```

So how to do that?

Below is part of my wcf code.

```
public string GetFirstName(byte[] source, int height, int width)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = ImageTypeConverter.ArrayToImage(source, height, width);
        bitmap.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "test" + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

        return "ImageSaveComplete";
    }
```

As you see I want to pass byte array and integer value.

Please let me know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send multiple parameters, strings, integers, etc:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);

    PropertyInfo variableHeight = new PropertyInfo(); 

    variableHeight.setName("height");
    variableHeight.setValue(value); // your variable value
    variableHeight.setType(Integer.class); // if its string type change to String.class
    request.addProperty(variableHeight);

    PropertyInfo variableWidth = new PropertyInfo();

    variableWidth.setName("width");
    variableWidth.setValue(value);
    variableWidth.setType(Integer.class);
    request.addProperty(variableWidth);
```

But for sending byte arrays im not sure, look at this :
http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=116